# Define a SqlDeveloper connection when no password is required for the database

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to define a connection in sqlDeveloper when the password is not required for the database? Thanks

Comment: What command was used to create the DB user account? Can you connect from other clients, and if so how?